# Using the max function in Pandas for Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am doing a tutorial online on Juypter notebook with Python and Pandas, and when I run the following code, I run into this error.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
    
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
    
%matplotlib inline

# reading the csv file
titanic = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv") 

titanic_class = titanic.groupby("Pclass")   
    
titanic_class.get_group(1)
titanic_class.max()
```

```bash
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-4d1be28a55cb> in <module>
      1 #max ticket fare paid
----> 2 titanic_class.max()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in f(self, **kwargs)
   1369                 # try a cython aggregation if we can
   1370                 try:
-> 1371                     return self._cython_agg_general(alias, alt=npfunc, **kwargs)
   1372                 except DataError:
   1373                     pass

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
    992     ) -> DataFrame:
    993         agg_blocks, agg_items = self._cython_agg_blocks(
--> 994             how, alt=alt, numeric_only=numeric_only, min_count=min_count
    995         )
    996         return self._wrap_agged_blocks(agg_blocks, items=agg_items)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in _cython_agg_blocks(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   1098             # Clean up the mess left over from split blocks.
   1099             for locs, result in zip(split_items, split_frames):
-> 1100                 assert len(locs) == result.shape[1]
   1101                 for i, loc in enumerate(locs):
   1102                     new_items.append(np.array([loc], dtype=locs.dtype))

AssertionError:
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong? The `titanic_class.sum()` & the `titanic_class.mean()` works without any error.

Comment: Can you post the link to the tutorial?

Comment: Sorry i can't. It's a tutorial on a paid site called pluralsight but i have the link to the csv file here though: https://gofile.io/d/mleyke. Let me know if pandas work for you on juypter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

The last column of the excel file has letters. Once I removed them, the max function worked.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when any column has empty (Nan) values. Try to remove those columns before using max.